# First Paragraph of Chapter 12 of Griffiths and Schroeter meaning

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

I am unsure what of Griffiths and Schroeter mean when they say

> This raises a profound question: Did the physical system "actually have" the attribute in questions *prior* to the measurement (the so-called **realist** viewpoint), or did the act of measurement itself "create" the property, limited only by the statistical constraints imposed by the wavefunction (the **orthodox** position), - or can we duck the issue entirely, on the grounds that it is "metaphysical" (the **agnostic** response)? (Griffiths & Schroeter pg.446)

Specifically, I'm confused on the metaphysical response. What are they referring to when they say "on the grounds *it* is metaphysical."? What is metaphysical according to the agnostics?

Comment: They're saying that the question of what is "really going on" is a question of *meta*physics, not physics.  Physics (as an empirical science) is concerned with the outcomes of experiments and building (usually mathematical) models to *describe* and *predict* those outcomes, but it doesn't take a stand on "what the universe is made of". Therefore, the agnostic stance is that we don't take a position on whether a system has attributes that are revealed or created by a measurement.